# React router pass callback with current route to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-router

I am using react with react router. Some of my components have sub-routes defined so I want to pass them a callback that enables to returning to a specific route/component. I want to avoid passing a string to a specific route (because of the dependency when routing changes happen in the code). So i prefer passing a callback and populating it with the value of match.url.

But this does not work: Instead of passing the value, match.url always refers to the current route.

**Parent component (simplified):**

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { history, match, contentId } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>Block 1</div>
          <div>Block 2</div>
          <div>Block 3</div>
        </div>
        {contentId && <MyChildComponent content={contentId} goBack={() => history.push(match.url)} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**My child component (simplified):**

```
export class MyChildComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div role="dialog" onClick={this.props.goBack} />
        </React.Fragment>),
    );
  }
}
```

**My router:**

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <div>
      <Route path="/result/:contentId?" component={ParentComponent} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

So when I go to /result I see - as expected - all but the child component. When navigating to /result/someId I see the child component but the goBack only refers to the current page instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my core-problem was that I needed at least one part of the child routes in the parent component. This lead to changing path props also in the parent component when child-routes were changing.

My solution: Store the current location in the constructor of the parent component and pass this as prop to child components to refer back. It works but has the drawback that one can not directly access child component routes because they will not refer back to the right parent path. For my use case this is fine but improvements are welcome.

**Parent component**

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.location = this.props.location.pathname;
    }

    render() {
      return (
          {contentId && <MyChildComponent content={contentId} goBack={() => 
          history.push(this.location)} />}
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
}

goBack(){
    this.props.history.goBack(); // You're not calling it from history
}

.....

<button onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back</button>
```

Comment: I edited my question because I think there is a misunderstanding. I don't want to pass history.goBack. I want to pass an arbitrary function that returns to current URL at the moment of passing the function. I want to use match.url for this in order to avoid dependencies on concrete router implementations (in case URLs change later on, the code should still work).

Comment: Good hint, yes, I tried that. The issue with all router-related props is that they update when routes change in child elements. At the end I just stored the parent route as state at component creation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using `push` to navigate to another route. So when you do `history.push('/result/someId')` you are adding another entry to history stack so `goBack` will navigate to the previous entry in the stack which is `/result`. It works as if you were a regular website and clicked a link - you could still go back even if what had changed was some dynamic parameter.

If you don't want to add up to history stack use - `history.replace('/result/someId')`

See [navigating with history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history#navigation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding another route to the history is fine. But I want to avoid passing a hard coded string because routing might change in the future. Instead I would like to pass the concrete value of match.url at the moment of passing it to the child component (and not updating on later URL changes).